# Can Super Duper perform "smart update" from SSD to HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, superduper, hdd

My goal is to create a bootable backup of my SSD boot drive on an external HDD. I'm using a Mac Pro mid-2010, so I can swap out the boot drive should my SSD ever get corrupted. Is there any reason Super Duper wouldn't be able to "smart update" a clone of the SSD onto an HDD? (And should I consider alternatives to Super Duper?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SuperDuper can do this. I've done it with a MacBook before. As far as SuperDuper is concerned, it's just two drives.

Answer (score 0):

*From the developer:*

> Of course. THere's nothing special about SSDs from a file perspective - they work just like HDDs.